# Does MariaDB support schema changes inside a transaction?

Tags: schema, mariadb

[MySQL doesn't support schema changes, inside a transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29943069/18706) so there's no way to roll back after during a failed migration involving schema changes.

This capability *is* supported by Postgres and SQLite. Any chance MariaDB supports it?

Comment: I think no, it isn't.

Comment: [from the manual](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/start-transaction/): "*DDL statements (CREATE, ALTER, DROP) [...] cause an implicit COMMIT*"

Answer (score 6):

No.

["DDL statements (CREATE, ALTER, DROP) [...] cause an implicit COMMIT"](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/start-transaction/)

Thanks horse with no name.